# webpack+angular2 error: Uncaught ReferenceError: __decorate is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

chrome console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: __decorate is not defined
this is code https://github.com/Dreampie/angular2-demo

run it:

npm install

npm run typings install

npm run start

open localhost:80 in browser

someone help?

Comment: "run it": No. Post a plunker,

Comment: Could it run with webpack? and not support load from github.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

remove from tsconfig.json

```
"declaration": true,
"noEmitHelpers": false,
"isolatedModules": false
```

Comment: Great! In my case, the `noEmitHelpers` was the culprit, the others weren't in my `tsconfig.json` file to begin with.

Comment: I'm on RC5. I added "declaration": true because i had __extends not defined. In other thread issue #16 mentioned to add "declaration": true. If i have declation i get __decorate is not defined.

If i remove everything mentioned above i get back __extends not defined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this is actually doing/how these were causing this problem? not a lot of help otherwise

Comment: Damn you are a wizard :)

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html for what these do.
declaration (default false) - Generates corresponding .d.ts file
noEmitHelpers (default false) - Do not generate custom helper functions like __extends in compiled output.
isolatedModules (default false) - Transpile each file as a separate module

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when creating  the code sharing NativeScript  https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro

but I only had to coment out this 2 lines:

```
    //"declaration": false,  
    //"noEmitHelpers": true,
```

Comment: Thanks, happened to me, too, removing `"noEmitHelpers": true` was sufficient.
I opened an issue: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/304

Comment: I just had the same issue but I wasn't sure if the NativeScript mobile part of the shared app needs the  `"noEmitHelpers": true,` so instead I put `"noEmitHelpers": false,` into the **"tsconfig.app.json"** file so it would only affect the typescript compiler options of the web browser portion of the project which also fixed this issue.