# Angular2 + Webpack UncaughtReferenceError __decorate is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack

After trying to migrate a functioning angular2 typescript app to webpack I get the following runtime error

```
app.js:38016Uncaught ReferenceError: __decorate is not defined
```

The code at the line where it blows up looks like this

```
NpnPortalService = __decorate([
            core_1.Injectable(), 
            __metadata('design:paramtypes', [http_1.Http])
        ], NpnPortalService);
```

Webpack doesn't complain when I do a build and I'm not seeing any typescript compile errors. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app/boot",
        polyfills: ['./node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js', './node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/
        }],
        noParse: [ './node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js' ]
    }
};
```

Here is my tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
  "files": [
    "app.component.ts",
    "../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

and here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>

    <!-- Set the base href -->
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <title>NPN Data Download Tool</title>

    <script src="dist/polyfills.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps Initialization -->
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        console.log(mapDiv.getAttribute("intialized"));
        if (!mapDiv.getAttribute("intialized")) {
          console.log("intializing google map");
          var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 40.750289, lng: -89.583163},
            zoom: 5
          });

          map.enableKeyDragZoom();
          var dz = map.getDragZoomObject();

          google.maps.event.addListener(dz, "dragend", function(bnds) {

            document.getElementById("ObservationBottomLeftX1").value = bnds.getSouthWest().lat();
            document.getElementById("ObservationBottomLeftY1").value = bnds.getSouthWest().lng();
            document.getElementById("ObservationUpperRightX2").value = bnds.getNorthEast().lat();
            document.getElementById("ObservationUpperRightY2").value = bnds.getNorthEast().lng();
            document.getElementById("necoords").innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>North East Corner</span>: " + bnds.getNorthEast().lat() + ", " + bnds.getNorthEast().lng();
            document.getElementById("swcoords").innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>South West Corner</span>: " + bnds.getSouthWest().lat() + ", " + bnds.getSouthWest().lng();
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed',
              function() {
                if (map.getZoom() < 3) {
                  map.setZoom(3);
                };
              });

          document.getElementById('map_canvas').setAttribute("intialized", true);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="./keydragzoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>

  <script src="dist/app.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Override Bootstrap css here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808303/webpackangular2-error-uncaught-referenceerror-decorate-is-not-defined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove `"noEmitHelpers": true` from your tsconfig

Comment: yeah I saw that other stackoverflow and tried that already with no luck :(

Comment: @apricity i've built your configuration and after removing noEmitHelpers it works.

Comment: @xphong, strange it wasn't working for me earlier.... but after making all the changes I posted in the answer I tried adding "noEmitHelpers": true back and it did indeed break again. Maybe something was cached or maybe there were additional issues.

Comment: @apricity I think when you change your tsconfig you need to kill your ng serve and start it back up to use the new config

Comment: Saved my day, I was using typedi for a typescript project (Nothing to do with angular) but this answer nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by using typings and mimicing this project: https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack

Here are the changed files (note to anyone who uses this answer I'm very new to angular/typescript/webpack so I might be doing some things incorrectly):

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfills: ['es6-shim/es6-shim.js', 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills'],
        app: "./app/boot.ts"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['ts-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->

    <!-- Set the base href -->
    <!--<base href="/">-->
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <title>NPN Data Download Tool</title>

    <script src="dist/polyfills.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps Initialization -->
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        console.log(mapDiv.getAttribute("intialized"));
        if (!mapDiv.getAttribute("intialized")) {
          console.log("intializing google map");
          var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 40.750289, lng: -89.583163},
            zoom: 5
          });

          map.enableKeyDragZoom();
          var dz = map.getDragZoomObject();

          google.maps.event.addListener(dz, "dragend", function(bnds) {

            document.getElementById("ObservationBottomLeftX1").value = bnds.getSouthWest().lat();
            document.getElementById("ObservationBottomLeftY1").value = bnds.getSouthWest().lng();
            document.getElementById("ObservationUpperRightX2").value = bnds.getNorthEast().lat();
            document.getElementById("ObservationUpperRightY2").value = bnds.getNorthEast().lng();

            document.getElementById("necoords").innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>North East Corner</span>: " + bnds.getNorthEast().lat() + ", " + bnds.getNorthEast().lng();
            document.getElementById("swcoords").innerHTML = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>South West Corner</span>: " + bnds.getSouthWest().lat() + ", " + bnds.getSouthWest().lng();
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed',
              function() {
                if (map.getZoom() < 3) {
                  map.setZoom(3);
                };
              });

          document.getElementById('map_canvas').setAttribute("intialized", true);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="./keydragzoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>

  <script src="dist/app.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Override Bootstrap css here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


</html>
```